# How to fill remaining space in div with pseudo elements?

Tags: css, background, pseudo-element

I'm trying to make a h2 element with a line in a background, but only in the remaining space. **I know the simplies way is to use span** inside H2, but user will generate content by WYSIWIG, so I can't use additional elements in h2. I tried many things with :before and :after, but with no success. Maybe someone dealt with this before and came up with clever idea?

[image: example]

Comment: You can always add that span with jQuery/etc. or PHP (if rendered by the backend engine) and then, simply apply your styles. AFAIK, the text within H2 must be in something, e.g. span to make that line. //at least that's what I do.

Comment: Yes, that's another way to do it, but the line will be added after document.ready, so the lines will appear with a delay. I was hoping there is a neat trick to do this in css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the pseudo element :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ms8pT/)**

```
<div id="content">
    <h2>Example title</h2>
    <p>.. content ..</p>
    <p>.. content ..</p>
    <h2>Example longer title</h2>
    <p>.. content ..</p>
    <p>.. content ..</p>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#content {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
h2 {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#fff;
    padding-right:20px;
    line-height:1.2em;
}
h2:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:0.6em;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    height:2px;
    background:blue;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: I think using background white (or another solid color) for the `h2` is not really good in some case like this http://jsfiddle.net/ms8pT/2/

Comment: that is true. @SimonRabbit do you have images as background of your titles?

Comment: You might want to use a relative unit to adjust the top margin of the blue line. `0.5em` would ensure the OP doesn't have to keep adjusting it for different font sizes: http://jsfiddle.net/ms8pT/3/

Comment: Thank you web-tiki! That's what I was hoping for and it works great! KUDOS! edit: nope, no images! just plain white.

Comment: @ChrisHardie thx for the suggestion, it is better with relative units. I updated my answers

Comment: @ChrisHardie that sounds logic, but `0.5em` may not be the correct value, I've tried setting `font-size` of `h2` to `50px` here http://jsfiddle.net/ms8pT/5/

Comment: @KingKing it works if you remove the `line-height` http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ms8pT/6/

Comment: @web-tiki not really, I've tried it using Opera, it's not really middle, in fact it's closer to the top, although it seems to look OK when the font-size is normal.

Comment: @KingKing you are right, the line-height property seems to interfere. But with this http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ms8pT/8/ it seems to be corrected.

Comment: Please note that the pseudo-element will be 100% of the relative element. Here the <div>. If you put `position:relative`on the <h2>, it will be the width of the <h2> tag...